# Node.JS - if a string includes some strings with any characters in between

Tags: node.js

I am testing a string that contains an identifier for which type of device submitted the string. The device type identifier will be something like "123456**FF789000AB" where the * denote any character could be used at this position. I run a series of functions to parse additional data and set variables based on the type of device submitting the data. Currently, I have the following statement:

```
if (payload[4].includes("02010612FF590080BC")) { function(topic, payload, intpl)};
```

The string tested in the includes() test will always start with 020106, but the next two characters could be anything. Is there a quick regex I could throw in the includes function, or should I organize the test in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

To match the "020106**FF590080BC" pattern, where `*` can be anything, you can use `RegExp.test()` and the regular expression `/020106..FF590080BC/`:

```
if (/020106..FF590080BC/.test(payload[4])) { ... }
```

Also, if you require that the pattern must match the beginning of the string:

```
if (/^020106..FF590080BC/.test(payload[4])) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, Cybersam. This is exactly what I was hoping to accomplish, and now that I understand the syntax I will use this method for quite a number of parsing tasks.